# Not able to see all the methods under dt accessor in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, timestamp

Maybe a silly question. I have been trying to use dt accessor in pandas to use datetime methods on certain date fields in my Data Frame.

Not sure why, but the after putting 'dt' accessor, Jupyter does not provide the list of methods available for use on a click of Tab button.

[image: Jupyter does not provide methods supported by dt accessor]

Things already tried:

1. Imported datetime library (Don't know why i felt it may fix the problem)
2. Searched Stackoverflow for an answer to this. Could not find one.
3. Checked the type of the column on which i am using the dt accessor. It is indeed a 'timestamp' object. See image below

[image: 'timestamp' object]

Comment: *not related to jupyter but*: to get and overview of an object's methods and attributes, you can always use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: @MrFuppes - Thanks. I did try that. It was useful. However, still wondering was there a reason why the auto-display of methods was not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

'dt' accessor only works and only is shown in Series that are datetime.

You should check the dateframe type as best practice, with:

```
raw_data.dtypes
```

In case you need to update Serie, you can do in this way:

```
raw_data['PAYMENT_DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(raw_data['PAYMENT_DATE'])
```

'dt' accessor should be shown now.